# Excel Copying work sheet from another workbook into existing workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copying

I am new to VBA and need a bit of help.

I am looking to create code that does the following:

I have three excel workbooks I am working with

```
my master: Master.Xlsm
NewEmployeeFile.xls
OldEmployeefile.xls
```

What I want to do is within my master. I want it to copy "SheetA" from     Newemployeefile.xls and copy it to sheet called "NewEmployeefile" within my master.
And
Copy "SheetA" from oldemployeefile.xls and copy it to sheet called "oldemployeefile" within my master.

Can someone please assist me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Run this macro in `Master.Xlsm`

```
Sub getEmployeefiles()
    Dim wb
    For Each wb In Array("NewEmployeefile.xls", "OldEmployeefile.xls")
        With Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & wb)
            .Sheets("SheetA").Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            .Close False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).name = left(wb, InStrRev(wb, ".") - 1)
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
```